# Resharper internal error when debugging in 64bits and using SMO APIs

Tags: resharper, smo, resharper-6.0

If I debug some unit tests with Resharper, and those unit tests use the SMO SDK, I get this error:

[image]

Any idea how to avoid it? I'm running ReSharper 6.1.37.86 (Full Edition)

**UPDATE**: After upgrading to Resharper 6.1.1000.82, I get a slightly different error:
[image]

Filed in JetBrain's issue tracker: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-326369

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a two-step workaround:

- Use .NET 3.5, not .NET 4.0.

After this change, debugger stopped crashing. However, it still was very slow, and sometimes my breakpoints were not hit. The second step that needs to be done for this workaround to make your debugger fully work is:

- Go to Properties of your .NET project, "Debug" tab, disable the option "Enable the Visual Studio hosting process"

An example of the effect these two changes have in your project files is this diff:
https://github.com/7digital/DatabaseMigraine/commit/badfebce83a1c4e39ddfce8a707b0e0ca62ad5a0